# mspdebug can't find libmsp430.so, but it is on my computer

Tags: linux-headers

I am running mspdebug with tilib driver, but mspdebug says:

`tilib: can't find libmsp430.so: libmsp430.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I have done a search and libmsp430 is located at /opt/ti/bin/libmsp430.so along with msp430-elf-gcc.

I read that I should add it to the $PATH variable (which I did and confirmed it was added to it), but I still get this same error.

Is there another location that I should place libmsp430.so so that it can be seen by mspdebug?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0):

I copied the file to /usr/lib/libmsp430.so and everything works! Makes sense as this is where the other .so and .o files are